# Behavior of SqlConnection.ClearPool with transactions

Tags: .net, sql-server, sqlclient

What is the behavior of [`SqlConnection.ClearPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool.aspx) if I pass as argument a connection used within a transaction (for example using a `System.Transactions.TransactionScope`)?

For example, in this snippet

```
using(var tx=new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
{
  var sqlConn=new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(...);
  /*do something with connection*/

  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ClearPool(sqlConn);

  tx.Complete();
}
```

with the `ClearPool` call am I clearing all the connections with the same connection string (regardless of transaction) or in fact am I closing only the connection I'm passing (because it is "associated" with the transaction)?

I searched on the Internet but I found nothing. From MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.clearpool.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx)) it's clear the behavior without transaction; moreover I understand that if I'm in a transaction the connection pool tries to give to me the connection I used before in that transaction (if it still exists). But it is not clear to me the behavior of `ClearPool` when called with a connection used in a transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I haven't found any official documentation about this specific scenario, I've realized a small sample (available at https://github.com/edymtt/sqlclientconnectionpool) that simulates this scenario. The important thing to do before running this sample is to stop MS DTC on the test machine -- so that we don't deal with distributed transactions and we don't miss that a new `SqlConnection` is created.

This way I've discovered that `SqlConnection.ClearPool` clears all the connections that has the same connection string of the connection passed as arguments, regardless of any transaction associated to the connection.